# See the current charging speed on Windows 10 for MSI laptops

Tags: windows-10, battery

I am looking for a program that can show the current charging speed on Windows 10 for MSI laptops.

Running `powercfg /batteryreport` in `cmd.exe` doesn't give the info directly (one has to do the math based on the log).

E.g. on Android I use the AccuBattery app:

[image]

Any license is ok.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any pointers are welcome.